# plugins in keywindow can't response user events?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

In my viewcontroller like this:

```
#import "PPSharedView.h"
@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    PPSharedView * sharedView = [[PPSharedView alloc] init];
    sharedView.topImageName = @"fenxiangdao";
    [sharedView sharedWithArrayImage:@[@"weixin_um",@"weixin_um",@"weixin_um",] titles:@[@"微信好友",@"微信好友",@"微信好友",]];
}
@end
```

In PPSharedView.h like this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface PPSharedView : UIView

-(void)sharedWithArrayImage:(nonnull NSArray *)arrImgs
                     titles:(nonnull NSArray *)arrTitles;

@end
```

In PPSharedView.m on the below:

```
-(void)sharedWithArrayImage:(NSArray *)arrImgs titles:(NSArray *)arrTitles{
    if (arrImgs.count != arrTitles.count) return;

    UIWindow * keyWindow = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
    UIView * backView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, kSCREEN_W, kSCREEN_H)];
    [keyWindow addSubview:backView];
    backView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    backView.alpha = 0.5;
    UITapGestureRecognizer * tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(clickRedview)];
    backView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [backView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
}

-(void)clickRedview{
    NSLog(@"adf");
}
```

When I run the app on the iPhone the backView on the screen but can't response click events.Anyone knows what's wrong with the code?Thank you very much!

Comment: try once in viewdidappear

Comment: @Anbu.karthik it does'n work anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In controller the sharedView should be referenced example:

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property(nonatomic, strong) PPSharedView * ppView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    PPSharedView * sharedView = [[PPSharedView alloc] init];
    self.ppView = sharedView;
    sharedView.topImageName = @"fenxiangdao";
    [sharedView sharedWithArrayImage:@[@"weixin_um",@"weixin_um",@"weixin_um",] titles:@[@"微信好友",@"微信好友",@"微信好友",]];
}


@end
```

If don't do this the sharedView will be destoryed!